# Custom dynamic error pages in Ruby on Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement custom dynamic error pages following this post:
http://www.perfectline.co.uk/blog/custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails

I did exactly what the blog post says. I included config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false in my environment.rb. But is not working.

My browser shows:

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/555" with {:method=>:get}
```

So, it looks like the rescues are not fired.
I get the following in my log file:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/555" with {:method=>:get}):
Rendering rescues/layout (not_found)
```

Is there some routing interfering with the code? I'm not sure what to look for. I'm running rails 2.3.5.

Here is the routes.rb file:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  # routing van property-url
  map.connect 'buy/:property_type_plural/:province/:city/:address/:house_number', :controller => 'properties' , :action => 'show', :id => 'whatever'
  map.myimmonatie 'myimmonatie' , :controller => 'myimmonatie/properties', :action => 'index'
  map.login "login", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "create", :conditions => {:method => :post}
  map.login "login", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "new"
  map.logout "logout", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "destroy"
  map.buy "buy", :controller => 'buy'
  map.sell "sell", :controller => 'sell'
  map.home "home", :controller => 'home'
  map.disclaimer "disclaimer", :controller => 'disclaimer'
  map.sign_up "sign_up", :controller => 'users', :action => :new
  map.contact "contact", :controller => 'contact'
  map.resources :user_sessions
  map.resources :contact
  map.resources :password_resets
  map.resources :messages
  map.resources :users, :only => [:index,:new,:create,:activate,:edit,:profile,:password]
  map.resources :images
  map.resources :activation , :only => [:new,:resend]
  map.resources :email
  map.resources :properties, :except => [:index,:destroy]

  map.namespace :admin do |admin|
       admin.resources :users
       admin.resources :properties
       admin.resources :order_items, :as => :orders
       admin.resources :blog_posts, :as => :blog
     end

     map.connect 'myimmonatie/:action' , :controller => 'users', :id => 'current', :requirements => {:action => /(profile)|(password)|(email)/}
     map.namespace :myimmonatie do |myimmonatie|
       myimmonatie.resources :messages, :controller => 'messages'
       myimmonatie.resources :password, :as => "password", :controller => 'users', :action => 'password'
       myimmonatie.resources :properties , :controller => 'properties'
       myimmonatie.resources :orders , :only => [:index,:show,:create,:new]
     end

  map.root :controller => "home"
  map.connect ':controller/:action'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end

ActionController::Routing::Translator.translate_from_file('config','i18n-routes.yml')
```

Comment: What do you have in **config/routes.rb**?

Comment: I added the file in the question

Answer (score 0):

The code works, something is wrong with the line in my environment.rb
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
It seems to be overridden somewhere.

So, CASE CLOSED, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rails detects when you are browsing with ip 127.0.0.1 and shows you the development environment errors even if you are in production environment. You should try accessing from a different machine to get the proper errors.